# Change file name on Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a lot of data with file names like this:

```
20110.bil
20111.bil
20112.bil
...
2011150.bil
2011151.bil
2011152.bil
```

The pattern of above file name is:

```
year+(0-152)
```

0-152 mean August 1 to December 31.

I want to change that file name into

```
20110801.bil
20110802.bil
20110803.bil
............
............
20111229.bil
20111230.bil
20111231.bil
```

The pattern of the file name that I want it is:

```
year+month+day.
```

How do I solve my problem?

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. What Linux distribution are you using? The `rename` utility can be useful here but the details depend on your implementation of it and that is different for different distros.

Answer (score 1):

How about this Bash solution?

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob extglob
for file in +([[:digit:]]).bil; do
    file_noext=${file%.bil}
    year=${file_noext::4}
    day=${file_noext:4}
    [[ -z $day ]] || ((0<=day && day<=152 && ${#year}==4)) || { echo "Error with file $file"; continue; }
    newname=$(date -d "$year-08-01 + $day days" '+%Y%m%d.bil')
    echo mv -nv "$file" "$newname"
done
```

- This will loop all the files of the form `X.bil` where `X` is a number (composed of digits only).
- For each file and after stripping the extension `.bil`, we extract the first four characters (the `year`) and we get the remaining digits in `day` variable.
- Then there's a line that checks whether everything is ok (`day` is non-empty, between 0 and 152, and `year` really has 4 characters).
- After that we use the `date` utility (hopefully you have a smart `date` like mine that can perform arithmetics with dates, here add days to a given one).
- Finally we perform the renaming (well, I left an `echo` in front of `mv`, so that the command is only shown, not performed; remove the `echo` if you're happy with it).

---

**Test.** I called this script `banana` (with the `echo` removed) and I `chmod +x banana`. Then:

```
$ mkdir scratch
$ cd scratch
$ touch 2011{0,42,100,151}.bil
$ ls
20110.bil  2011100.bil  2011151.bil  201142.bil
$ ./banana
`20110.bil' -> `20110801.bil'
`2011100.bil' -> `20111109.bil'
`2011151.bil' -> `20111230.bil'
`201142.bil' -> `20110912.bil'
$ ls
20110801.bil  20110912.bil  20111109.bil  20111230.bil
```

Looks good!

Comment: Ah, dense code, sigh... Why didn't I think ot that?

Answer (score 0):

The following script will do it for you:

```
 #!/bin/bash


 > out.txt
 while read line; do
    mytmp=$(echo $line | sed 's/.bil$//' | sed 's/^2011//' )
    echo $mytmp
    if [ $mytmp -lt 31 ]; then
            MONTH=08
            DAY=$(( $mytmp + 1))
    elif  [ $mytmp -lt 61 ]; then
            MONTH=09
            DAY=$(( $mytmp - 30 ))
    elif  [ $mytmp -lt 92 ]; then
            MONTH=10
            DAY=$(( $mytmp - 60 ))
    elif  [ $mytmp -lt 122 ]; then
            MONTH=11
            DAY=$(( $mytmp - 91 ))
    elif  [ $mytmp -lt 153 ]; then
            MONTH=12
            DAY=$(( $mytmp -121 ))
    fi
    echo "2011$MONTH$DAY.bil" >> out.txt

 done < data
```

It works like this: it reads a file called *data* line by line, and puts its output into a file called *out.txt* (change this as it best suits you). The first line clears the output file, then reads the data file stripping the string of the initial *2011* and of the final *.bil*. What is left is the day coding. Then, depending on the day coding, it determines the corresponding month and day, and it reconstructs the string by pre-pending *2011*, appending *.bil*, and putting the final string into the file *output.txt*.